# How to add New Static page in MVC 4 Razor C# solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a solution in ASP.net MVC 4 Razor C# with test module. I want to add a static page in this solution. I have a HTML page with me, and I want to add a page in the Solution with same design. How do I add it ? I have AccountController and HomeController in solution already.

Please Help

Thanks in Advance
Nils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to the root of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a simple HTML page. Ensure the extension is HTML and not CSHTML.

Answer (score 0):

add routes.IgnoreRoute("filename.html") in your routeconfig file and then   hit  localhost/filename.html.. it will work..